# Understanding snapshots in CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: java, concurrency, snapshot, copy-on-write

I have few issues in understanding this concept. Please correct me where I am wrong.

Basically, iteration makes a snapshot (copy) of original array, thus threads that modify collection won't affect our iteration because iteration uses a copy. So no ConcurrentException here, nice.

But then I also read that any modification is done by making a copy of original collection and using that copy to make changes. Then it sets it to original one.

Can someone tell me why is there need to make a copy when modifying, when iteration already uses its own copy. Why have 2 copes, one for read, one for write?

I think I said something incorrect, so please can you point what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `CopyOnWriteArrayList` creates an iterator, the "snapshot" is a reference to its current array - not a copy of the array.

The iterator can use a reference to the array because the array is never modified. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` does that the name says: it makes a new copy of the array when anything is changed. If some iterator using the old array at the same time, that's not a problem, the iterator will just keep using the old array and it will not see any of the modifications made to the list. This makes the iterator "weakly consistent."

Comment: As you said: "Iterator will just keep using the old array and it will not see any of the modification made to the list". Now my question.. If it doesn't see any modifications, why do modifications have to be made on a copy?

Comment: If modifications were made on the original array, they would be seen by the iterator. You would need to synchronize list traversal with list modification to get memory consistency guarantees (adding an item should *"happen-before"* the same item is retrieved). That's a performance hit, and the users and the designers of  `CopyOnWriteArrayList` don't want that.

Comment: Ahh this topic is killing me :D How would had it been seen by iterator when we just agreed that any modification will not be seen by iterator? Because it takes snapshot at the time iterator was made.

Comment: The "snapshot" the iterator takes is not a copy of the backing array, it's a reference to the backing array at the time the iterator is created. This means that any modifications made to the array would be seen by the iterator. Since we don't want this to happen, it  means that *no* modifications can be made to the the array.

Comment: Thanks Joni. One thing is left to ask. What if iteration takes 5 seconds and during iteration I write something. Although write is made on a copy, it would still have to set those new values to original array. So how does it handle it now? Looks like our snapshot is going to be changed after all, even thought we were modifying a copy.

Comment: @AnaMaria why do you think “it would still have to set those new values to original array”? The whole point of this class is that it does *not* modify the original array.

Comment: @Holger Yes it doesn't modify original array. It modifies copy. But what happens when it finishes with modification? It sets values from copy array into original array. Or that's what I understood..

Comment: No, it does not. It does not modify the original array. Otherwise, the original array couldn’t be called “snapshot”.

Comment: @Holger, Joni Then I was looking at this entire time wrong. Can you please correct me if I am wrong? Let me sum it. Read makes a snapshot (like a schreenshot) of array from some time. Any Write will be made on copy and remain in copy when finished. If I want to make iteration again it will make new snapshot from NEW array (previously changed by Write). After Write, array will hold difference reference.

Comment: That sounds right. A change to the makes it compute a new backing array.  When done, CopyOnWriteArrayList uses a simple reference assignment similar to `this.array = modifiedArray` to switch to use the new backing array - the content of the arrays is not modified. Existing iterators keep a reference to the old backing array. The source code is fairly readable - check out how the `add` and `iterator` methods are implemented https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/1982432db4e35626cfe693e0ec6bbc72fa32a24e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` says the following:

> The "snapshot" style iterator method *uses a reference to the state of the array at the point that the iterator was created*. This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You asked:

> Basically, iteration makes a snapshot (copy) of original array, thus threads that modify collection won't affect our iteration because iteration uses a copy. So no ConcurrentException here, nice.
>
> ...
>
> I think I said something incorrect, so please can you point what am I missing?

The javadoc does not say that the iterator **copies** the state of the list, or makes a **snapshot**.  It says that it uses a **reference** to the state of the list at the point in time that the iterator.

The state copying happens when the list is mutated, as explained elsewhere in the javadoc.

This is obviously what you were missing.

<sup>Hints: 1) Always read the javadoc carefully. 2) If you want to confirm what the javadoc says, read the source code.  But bear in mind that the source code may include implementation details that are not part of the API spec, and may change between different Java versions.</sup>

---

Followup question.

> Why is there need to make modifications on copy, when iterator uses snapshot and it doesn't see any modifications until it is finished?

Because if `CopyOnWriteArrayList` *didn't* make a fresh copy each time the list is modified, then existing iterators *would* see the modifications ... in all ill-defined way.

The other alternatives are:

1. Use a lock to block any modifications while the list is being iterated.  This would be a concurrency bottleneck.
2. Create the snapshot each time you start an iteration.  This would also be a concurrency bottleneck because you need to block modifications while the snapshot is created.

Note that `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is designed for use-cases where the list is most read and seldom modified.  For such use-cases, copying on modify is a good strategy.  But if the list needs to be modified a lot, this is a bad strategy ... and the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is the wrong choice.

Comment: Thanks, of course I read docs. Question is rather more of a logic type and when I think about it, I asked it little wrongly. I  will ask same question I asked Joni. Why is there need to make modifications on copy, when iterator uses snapshot and it doesn't see any modifications until it is finished?

Comment: *"Thanks, of course I read docs."* - The hint was to read the javadocs **carefully** :-).